# Docpad Livereload plugin + Cloud9 IDE

Tags: cloud9-ide, docpad

Has anyone successfully got this combination working?

It seems to run correctly on the client side, but there's something about Cloud9's file system that means changes aren't detected when files are saved, so I'm having to restart the app every time.

Comment: I don't think you should be running live reload if you're not developing everything locally... If you're developing on a remote server AFAIK you will always need to reload the page in order to get the changes.

Comment: Is regeneration not working at all? If so try this: http://docpad.org/docs/troubleshoot#watching-doesn-t-work-works-only-some-of-the-time-or-i-get-eisdir-errors

Comment: That's right, no regeneration at all. Tried the suggested config but no luck, I can only assume it is something to do with their environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is that cloud 9 gives u only one port(process.env.PORT) and you are using this port for running web server and you don't any have additional port for live-reload server.
for CSS you can use  [Live.js](http://livejs.com)

Answer (score 0):

Safareli is correct that Cloud 9 gives you only one port, but Live.js, the website Safareli linked in fact does work with refreshing everything, although I don't know how taxing it is to C9 since it is refreshing for headers pretty much all the time.